# How can we use tqdm in a parallel execution with joblib?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib, tqdm

I want to run a function in parallel, and wait until all parallel nodes are done, using joblib. Like in the example:

```
from math import sqrt
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(sqrt)(i ** 2) for i in range(10))
```

But, I want that the execution will be seen in a single progressbar like with **tqdm**, showing how many jobs has been completed.

How would you do that?

Comment: http://danshiebler.com/2016-09-14-parallel-progress-bar/ Maybe this site can help you.

Comment: See niedakh just underneath !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem consists of many parts, you could split the parts into `k` subgroups, run each subgroup in parallel and update the progressbar in between, resulting in `k` updates of the progress.

This is demonstrated in the following example from the documentation.

```
>>> with Parallel(n_jobs=2) as parallel:
...    accumulator = 0.
...    n_iter = 0
...    while accumulator < 1000:
...        results = parallel(delayed(sqrt)(accumulator + i ** 2)
...                           for i in range(5))
...        accumulator += sum(results)  # synchronization barrier
...        n_iter += 1
```

https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html#reusing-a-pool-of-workers

Comment: How does this answer the question about "a single progressbar"?

Comment: This absolutely doesn't answer the question about the progress bar though

Answer (score 59):

Just put `range(10)` inside `tqdm(...)`! It probably seemed too good to be true for you, but it really works (on my machine):

```
from math import sqrt
from joblib import Parallel, delayed  
from tqdm import tqdm  
result = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(sqrt)(i ** 2) for i in tqdm(range(100000)))
```

Comment: This only shows progress when the process starts, not when it is finished: `Parallel(n_jobs=10)(delayed(time.sleep)(i ** 2) for i in tqdm(range(10)))`

Comment: It works, but not with a list of strings for example... Also tried wrapping the list in `iter`...

Comment: @curious95 Try putting the list into a generator, the following seems to work for me: 

`from math import sqrt
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing  
from tqdm import tqdm  
rng = range(100000)
rng = ['a','b','c','d']
for j in range(20):
    rng += rng
def get_rng():
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(rng)):
        yield rng[i]
        
        
result = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(sqrt)(len(i) ** 2) for i in tqdm(get_rng()))`

Comment: In another question, there is a very elegant [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58936697/5299750) to this problem.

Comment: This won't work, `tqdm` will go to %100 immediately.

Answer (score 51):

I've created [pqdm](https://github.com/niedakh/pqdm) a parallel tqdm wrapper with concurrent futures to comfortably get this done, give it a try!

To install

```
pip install pqdm
```

and use

```
from pqdm.processes import pqdm
# If you want threads instead:
# from pqdm.threads import pqdm

args = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# args = range(1,6) would also work

def square(a):
    return a*a

result = pqdm(args, square, n_jobs=2)
```

Comment: Well done guy ! Can't stand why you're not accepted. Big Thank You !

Comment: Unfortunately this fails for me. I am not sure why, but it looks like pqdm does not wait until the end of the function calls. I do not have time now to create a MWE. Still, thanks for the effort (and +1).

Comment: @YairDaon maybe try it will work with the bounded executor, try adding `bounded=True` to pqdm.

Comment: Does it work over list comprehensions?

Comment: Interesting library. Can you tell us in what way it differs or is better than `p_tqdm` which is found at https://github.com/swansonk14/p_tqdm
Seems like the latter is more developed.

Comment: pqdm does a similar thing, but pqdm does not depend on pathos and you can easily exchange tqdm variants (like use slack_tqdm or discord_tqdm instead of the main tqdm.auto). Not sure what you mean by more developed, i'm a fan of simple tools for simple tasks, so pqdm is being lightweight, as dependency-less as possible.

Comment: This is a great library! It's such a breeze to use

Answer (score 27):

Modifying [nth's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61027781/394430) to permit a dynamic flag to use TQDM or not and to specify the total ahead of time so that the status bar fills in correctly.

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
from joblib import Parallel

class ProgressParallel(Parallel):
    def __init__(self, use_tqdm=True, total=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self._use_tqdm = use_tqdm
        self._total = total
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with tqdm(disable=not self._use_tqdm, total=self._total) as self._pbar:
            return Parallel.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def print_progress(self):
        if self._total is None:
            self._pbar.total = self.n_dispatched_tasks
        self._pbar.n = self.n_completed_tasks
        self._pbar.refresh()
```

Comment: For anyone wondering (like me), adding this to Joblib itself as an optional feature has been discussed on the issue tracker: <https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/972>

Answer (score 20):

There is no need to install additional packages. You can use tqdm's native support in the *contrib.concurrent*:
https://tqdm.github.io/docs/contrib.concurrent/

```
from tqdm.contrib.concurrent import process_map
# If you want threads instead:
# from tqdm.contrib.concurrent import thread_map
import time

args = range(5)

def square(a):
    time.sleep(a)
    return a*a

result = process_map(square, args, max_workers=2)
```

Comment: I don't know why no upvotes. This is one of the best answers for doing this kind of thing.

Comment: By far the simplest solution

Answer (score 18):

As noted above, solutions that simply wrap the iterable passed to `joblib.Parallel()` do not truly monitor the progress of execution. Instead, I suggest subclassing `Parallel` and overriding the `print_progress()` method, as follows:

```
import joblib
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

class ProgressParallel(joblib.Parallel):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with tqdm() as self._pbar:
            return joblib.Parallel.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def print_progress(self):
        self._pbar.total = self.n_dispatched_tasks
        self._pbar.n = self.n_completed_tasks
        self._pbar.refresh()
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's possible workaround

```
def func(x):
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 10))
    return x

def text_progessbar(seq, total=None):
    step = 1
    tick = time.time()
    while True:
        time_diff = time.time()-tick
        avg_speed = time_diff/step
        total_str = 'of %n' % total if total else ''
        print('step', step, '%.2f' % time_diff, 
              'avg: %.2f iter/sec' % avg_speed, total_str)
        step += 1
        yield next(seq)

all_bar_funcs = {
    'tqdm': lambda args: lambda x: tqdm(x, **args),
    'txt': lambda args: lambda x: text_progessbar(x, **args),
    'False': lambda args: iter,
    'None': lambda args: iter,
}

def ParallelExecutor(use_bar='tqdm', **joblib_args):
    def aprun(bar=use_bar, **tq_args):
        def tmp(op_iter):
            if str(bar) in all_bar_funcs.keys():
                bar_func = all_bar_funcs[str(bar)](tq_args)
            else:
                raise ValueError("Value %s not supported as bar type"%bar)
            return Parallel(**joblib_args)(bar_func(op_iter))
        return tmp
    return aprun

aprun = ParallelExecutor(n_jobs=5)

a1 = aprun(total=25)(delayed(func)(i ** 2 + j) for i in range(5) for j in range(5))
a2 = aprun(total=16)(delayed(func)(i ** 2 + j) for i in range(4) for j in range(4))
a2 = aprun(bar='txt')(delayed(func)(i ** 2 + j) for i in range(4) for j in range(4))
a2 = aprun(bar=None)(delayed(func)(i ** 2 + j) for i in range(4) for j in range(4))
```

Comment: It is a walk around, but the progress bar updates only when a task is dispatched. The better timing to update the progress bar is the time when the task is completed.

Answer (score 6):

I created the [tqdm_joblib](https://github.com/louisabraham/tqdm_joblib) to solve this issue.

Installation: `pip install tqdm-joblib`

From the readme:

Simple snippet copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58936697/5133167 packaged for simple reuse.

```py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from tqdm_joblib import tqdm_joblib

with tqdm_joblib(desc="My calculation", total=10) as progress_bar:
    Parallel(n_jobs=16)(delayed(sqrt)(i**2) for i in range(10))
```

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way to do it. As a suggestion, you can edit your answer and mention how to install it:
`pip install tqdm-job` from https://pypi.org/project/tqdm-joblib/

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers including classes by [user394430](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61900501/11829398) or [nth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61027781/11829398) worked for me.

But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58936697/11829398) from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24983493/tracking-progress-of-joblib-parallel-execution) works perfectly. Reposting for ease.

```py
import contextlib
import joblib
from tqdm import tqdm

@contextlib.contextmanager
def tqdm_joblib(tqdm_object):
    """Context manager to patch joblib to report into tqdm progress bar given as argument"""
    class TqdmBatchCompletionCallback(joblib.parallel.BatchCompletionCallBack):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            tqdm_object.update(n=self.batch_size)
            return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

    old_batch_callback = joblib.parallel.BatchCompletionCallBack
    joblib.parallel.BatchCompletionCallBack = TqdmBatchCompletionCallback
    try:
        yield tqdm_object
    finally:
        joblib.parallel.BatchCompletionCallBack = old_batch_callback
        tqdm_object.close()
```

Then wrap as a context manager

```py
from math import sqrt
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

with tqdm_joblib(tqdm(desc="My calculation", total=10)) as progress_bar:
    Parallel(n_jobs=16)(delayed(sqrt)(i**2) for i in range(10))
```

Works with versions:

- joblib - 1.2.0
- tqdm - 4.64.1
- python - 3.9.13

Answer (score 0):

copy paste from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76726101/5105118)

---

As of joblib v1.3.0, released in June 2023, there's an easier way to wrap `joblib.Parallel` with the tqdm progress bar (inspired by [this comment](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/972#issuecomment-1623366702)).

This progress bar will track job completion, not job enqueueing. Previously this required a special context manager. Here's an example:

```py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from tqdm import tqdm

import time
import random

# Our example worker will sleep for a certain number of seconds.

inputs = list(range(10))
random.shuffle(inputs)

def worker(n_seconds):
    time.sleep(n_seconds)
    return n_seconds

# Run the worker jobs in parallel, with a tqdm progress bar.
# We configure Parallel to return a generator.
# Then we wrap the generator in tqdm.
# Finally, we execute everything by converting the tqdm generator to a list.

outputs = list(
    tqdm(
        # Note the new return_as argument here, which requires joblib >= 1.3:
        Parallel(return_as="generator", n_jobs=3)(
            delayed(worker)(n_seconds) for n_seconds in inputs
        ),
        total=len(inputs),
    )
)
print(outputs)
```