# Infinite wait when running a Python ProcessPoolExecutor.map()-method

Tags: python, parallel-processing

Infinite wait when running Python `ProcessPoolExecutor.map()`-method

When `n` is 10000 to 20000, it works normally, but there is no response until it is forcefully terminated at 100,000.

Other machines with 4 core and 32 GB RAM work, but only this machine does not work.

These are the machine specs :

[image]

Any reason?

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from tqdm import tqdm

def test_func(x):
    return x+1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 100000
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(4) as p:
        lst = list( tqdm( p.map( test_func,
                                 [i for i in range(n)]
                                 ),
                          total = n,
                          leave = True
                          )
                    )
        # tried the same without a tqdm()-decorated GUI-progress monitor
        #lst = list(      p.map( test_func,
        #                        [i for i in range(n)]
        #                        )
        #                 )
```

I tried removing `tqdm()`, increasing `ulimit` and changing Python version from 3.9 to 3.10, but all did not work.

Comment: Your `test_func` isn't a good use case for multiprocessing. But you should actively use `.map`s `chunksize` agrument. E.g. try `p.map(test_func, range(n), chunksize=n // 4)`. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map): _" For very long iterables, using a large value for chunksize can significantly improve performance compared to the default size of 1"_.

Comment: You souldn't use tqdm in a multiprocessing environment. There are modules for that, see [pqdm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37804279/how-can-we-use-tqdm-in-a-parallel-execution-with-joblib) for example. Regarding the number of items, most of the time should be spend in inter-process communication unless `test_func` is expensive to compute 1 item. If `test_func` is cheap, then Python is simply not designed to compute this efficiently (because of IPC for processes and GIL for threads and no other standard solution for parallel computing in CPython yet).

Comment: @Timus `chunksize` worked for me. thanks.