# Intermediate results from joblib

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, joblib

I'm trying to learn the [`joblib`](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html) module as an alternative to the builtin `multiprocessing` module in python. I'm used to using `multiprocessing.imap` to run a function over an iterable and returning the results as they come in. In this minimal working example, I can't figure out how to do it with joblib:

```
import joblib, time

def hello(n):
    time.sleep(1)
    print "Inside function", n
    return n

with joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=1) as MP:

    func = joblib.delayed(hello)
    for x in MP(func(x) for x in range(3)):
        print "Outside function", x
```

Which prints:

```
Inside function 0
Inside function 1
Inside function 2
Outside function 0
Outside function 1
Outside function 2
```

I'd like to see the output:

```
Inside function 0
Outside function 0
Inside function 1
Outside function 1
Inside function 2
Outside function 2
```

Or something similar, indicating that the iterable `MP(...)` is not waiting for all the results to complete. For longer demo change `n_jobs=-1` and `range(100)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get **Immediate results from joblib**, for instance:

```
from joblib._parallel_backends import MultiprocessingBackend

class ImmediateResult_Backend(MultiprocessingBackend):
    def callback(self, result):
        print("\tImmediateResult function %s" % (result))

    # Overload apply_async and set callback=self.callback
    def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
        applyResult = super().apply_async(func, self.callback)
        return applyResult

joblib.register_parallel_backend('custom', ImmediateResult_Backend, make_default=True)

with joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=2) as parallel:
    func = parallel(delayed(hello)(y) for y in range(3))
    for f in func:
        print("Outside function %s" % (f))
```

**Output**:
Note: I use `time.sleep(n * random.randrange(1,5))` in `def hello(...)`, therefore `processes` become different ready.

> Inside function 0
>   Inside function 1
>       ImmediateResult function [0]
>   Inside function 2
>       ImmediateResult function [1]
>       ImmediateResult function [2]
>   Outside function 0
>   Outside function 1
>   Outside function 2

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - joblib:0.11***

Comment: This is great, thank you! I didn't realize you could hook into a new function, I didn't know what to call it. It's worth noting (after looking into it): "Warning: this function is experimental and subject to change in a future version of joblib."

Comment: @Hooked: _change_ does not mean **drop** in a future version. Beside this I could also get Immediate results using a **queue** instead of `hook`.

Answer (score 6):

stovfl's answer is elegant, but it only works for the first batches dispatched. In the example, it works because the workers never starve (`n_tasks < 2*n_jobs`). For this approach to work, the callback originally passed to `apply_async` must also be called. This is an instance of `BatchCompletionCallBack`, which schedules the next batch of tasks to be processed.

One possible solution is to wrap up arbitrary callbacks in a callable object, like this (tested in joblib==0.11, py36):

```
from joblib._parallel_backends import MultiprocessingBackend
from joblib import register_parallel_backend, parallel_backend
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import time

class MultiCallback:
    def __init__(self, *callbacks):
        self.callbacks = [cb for cb in callbacks if cb]

    def __call__(self, out):
        for cb in self.callbacks:
            cb(out)

class ImmediateResultBackend(MultiprocessingBackend):
    def callback(self, result):
        print("\tImmediateResult function %s" % result)

    def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
        cbs = MultiCallback(callback, self.callback)
        return super().apply_async(func, cbs)

register_parallel_backend('custom', ImmediateResultBackend)

def hello(n):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Inside function", n)
    return n

with parallel_backend('custom'):
    res = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(hello)(y) for y in range(6))
```

Output

```
Inside function 0
Inside function 1
    ImmediateResult function [0]
    ImmediateResult function [1]
Inside function 3
Inside function 2
    ImmediateResult function [3]
    ImmediateResult function [2]
Inside function 4
    ImmediateResult function [4]
Inside function 5
    ImmediateResult function [5]
```

Comment: Works nicely, thanks you! As a sidenote: the result in `callback` will then be a list of results. Also, if you want to catch the currently active backend you can let the `ImmediateResultBackend` inherit from `type(joblib.parallel.get_active_backend()[0])`. Like so: `class ImmediateResultBackend(type(joblib.parallel.get_active_backend()[0])): ...`. And finally it might make sense to deregister the backend again with: `del joblib.parallel.BACKENDS["custom"]`.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> import joblib, time
>>> 
>>> def hello(n):
...     time.sleep(1)
...     print "Inside function", n
...     return n
... 
>>> with joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=1) as MP:
...     func = joblib.delayed(hello)
...     res = MP(func(x) for x in range(3))  # This is not an iterator.
... 
Inside function 0
Inside function 1
Inside function 2
>>> type(res)
<type 'list'>
```

What you are dealing with is not a generator. Therefore you should not expect that it will provide you with intermediate results. Nothing that I read in the docs seem to mention otherwise (or I didn't read the relevant parts).

You are welcome to read the docs and search for "intermediate" results topic:
https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/search.html?q=intermediate&check_keywords=yes&area=default

My understanding is that each call to `parallel` is a barrier, and in order to have intermediate results, you need to chunk the processing:

```
>>> import joblib, time
>>> 
>>> def hello(n):
...     time.sleep(1)
...     print "Inside function", n
...     return n
... 
>>> with joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=1) as MP:
...     func = joblib.delayed(hello)
...     for chunk in range(3):
...         x = MP(func(y) for y in [chunk])
...         print "Outside function", x
... 
Inside function 0
Outside function [0]
Inside function 1
Outside function [1]
Inside function 2
Outside function [2]
>>>
```

If you want to get technical, there is a callback mechanism, but it is used exclusively for progress reporting (`BatchCompletionCallBack`), but you would need more involved code changes.

Comment: I'm not sure how your code block differs from mine -- all you've done is move the assignment `res` into the loop statement and add a comment. The problem still remains, I'm looking for a way to have joblib return intermediate results. The output of your answer does not match the expected output, in fact it returns the same thing I identified as the problem!

Comment: I said "Your code is equivalent to", that's pretty clear what that means. I have changed it to a snippet to make it less confusing

Comment: So to be clear, it is not possible to use joblib without computing the entire result set first? I understand our code blocks produce a list that has to be completed before displaying, but can one use joblib to do so? What is the `multiprocessing.imap` equivalent?  [if nothing else, this helped refine my question]